# Why replacing values in numpy array does not always work

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, overwrite

I am trying to replace/overwrite values in a array using the following commands:

```
import numpy as np
test = np.array([[4,5,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,6]])
test
Out[20]:
array([[4., 5., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 6.]])

test[np.where(test[...,0] != 0)][...,1:3] = np.array([[10,11]])
test
Out[22]:
array([[4., 5., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 6.]])
```

However, as one can see in Out22, the array test has not been modified. So I am concluding that it is not possible to simply overwrite a part of a array or just few cells.

Nevertheless, in other contexts, it is possible to overwrite few cells of a array. For example, in the below code:

```
test = np.array([[1,2,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,3]])
test
Out[11]:
array([[1., 2., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 3.]])

test[test>0]
Out[12]:
array([1., 2., 3.])

test[test>0] = np.array([4,5,6])
test
Out[14]:
array([[4., 5., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 6.]])
```

Therefore, my 2 questions:

1- Why does the first command

```
test[np.where(test[...,0] != 0)][...,1:3] = np.array([10,11])
```

does not allow modifying the array test ? Why does not it allow accessing the array cells and overwrite them?

2- How could I make it work considering that for my code I would need to select the cells using the command above?

Many thanks!

Comment: The `test[where...]` step makes a copy.  The following `[...]=...` modifies that copy, not the original.  A `view` pass the changes through, but not a copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll do you one up.  This *does* work:

```
test[...,1:3][np.where(test[...,0] != 0)] = np.array([[10,11]])

array([[ 4, 10, 11],
       [ 0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  6]])
```

Why?  It's the combination of two factors - `numpy` indexing and `.__setitem__` calls.

The `python` interpreter sort of reads lines backwards.  And when it gets to `=`, it tries to call `.__setitem__` on the furthest thing to the left.  `__setitem__` is (hopefully) a method of the object, and has two inputs, the target and the indices (whatever is between `[...]` just before it).

```
a[b] = c  #is intepreted as
a.__setitem__(b, c)
```

Now, when we index in `numpy` we have three basic ways we can do it.

- slicing (returns views)
- 'advanced indexing' (returns copies)
- 'simple indexing' (also returns copies)

One major difference between "advanced" and "simple" indexing is that a `numpy` array's `__setitem__` function can interpret advanced indexes.  And `views` mean the data addresses are the same, so we don't need `__setitem__` to get to them.

So:

```
test[np.where(test[...,0] != 0)][...,1:3] = np.array([[10,11]])  #is intepreted as

(test[np.where(test[...,0] != 0)]).__setitem__( slice([...,1:3]), 
                                                np.array([[10,11]]))
```

But, since `np.where(test[...,0] != 0)` is an `advanced index`, `(test[np.where(test[...,0] != 0)])` returns a copy, which is then lost because it is never assigned.  It does take the elements we want and set them to `[10,11]`, but the result is lost in the buffer somewhere.

If we do:

```
test[..., 1:3][np.where(test[..., 0] != 0)] = np.array([[10, 11]]) #is intepreted as

(test[..., 1:3]).__setitem__( np.where(test[...,0] != 0), np.array([[10,11]]) )
```

`test[...,1:3]` is a view,  so it still points to the same memory.  Now `setitem` looks for the locations in `test[...,1:3]` that correspond to `np.where(test[...,0] != 0)`, and set them equal to `np.array([[10,11]])`.  And everything works.

You can also do this:

```
test[np.where(test[...,0] != 0), 1:3] = np.array([10, 11])
```

Now, since all the indexing is in one set of brackets, it's calling `test.__setitem__` on those indices, which sets the data correctly as well.

Even simpler (and most pythonic) would be:

```
test[test[...,0] != 0, 1:3] = np.array([10,11])
```